# Despite calling SetMetadataAsync() and then UploadBlobAsync() no metadata or tags is found in the blob

Tags: azure, tags, metadata, azure-blob-storage

In my SF application I call the following C# code:

```
private readonly BlobContainerClient containerClient = null;
private readonly IDictionary<string, string> metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();

DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
this.metadata.Clear();
this.metadata.Add("tag1", blobBasicName);
blobName = string.Format("{0}/{1:00}_{2:00}_{3:00}/{4:00}_{5:00}_{6:00}",
    blobBasicName, now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(objectToWriteToBlob))
{
    await this.containerClient.SetMetadataAsync(metadata);
    await this.containerClient.UploadBlobAsync(blobName, ms);
}
```

And can see the uploaded blobs in Azure portal, but the metadata is not there:

[image: azure screenshot]

Also I try to retrieve the list of blobs for the storage account, and the `blob.tags` is not set there either:

```
container_client = ContainerClient.from_connection_string(conn_str, container_name=container_name)

blob_list = []
print('Fetching blobs from %s...' % container_name)
for blob in container_client.list_blobs():
    if blob.name.startswith(MY_BLOB_PREFIX) and blob.size > 500:
        print('blob name = %s, tags = %s' % (blob.name, blob.tags))
        blob_list.append(blob)
print('Fetched %d non-empty blobs from %s' % (len(blob_list), container_name))
```

[image: cmd screenshot]

Comment: Try uploading first, then set metadata.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're actually setting the metadata for the `blob container` instead of `blob itself`, since you're using the `SetMetadataAsync` method based on `blob container object`.

If you want to set metadata for a blob during uploading, you should use the code below:

```
private readonly BlobContainerClient containerClient = null;
private readonly IDictionary<string, string> metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();

DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
this.metadata.Clear();
this.metadata.Add("tag1", blobBasicName);
blobName = string.Format("{0}/{1:00}_{2:00}_{3:00}/{4:00}_{5:00}_{6:00}",
    blobBasicName, now.Year, now.Month, now.Day, now.Hour, now.Minute, now.Second);

var blobclient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobName);


using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(objectToWriteToBlob))
{
     blobclient.Upload(ms, null, metadata, null, null, null);
}
```

Comment: This has worked, I can see the added metadata blog in portal.azure.com, thank you. Is metadata different from tags. How to set a tag for a blob, could you please give a hint? I cannot find it in [the BlobClient doc for C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobclient?view=azure-dotnet), but the Python doc mentions `blob.tags`.

Comment: @AlexanderFarber, yes, tag is different from metadata. And currently, the tags should not be supported by a blob(it only applies  to blob storage account, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/tag-support#microsoftstorage)). And for the "tags" you mentioned in python, I think it may be [blob index tag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-index-how-to?tabs=azure-portal).